# Can I put 2 models in a single class in Django Views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Objective: I'm trying to display products and orders from 2 different tables in a template. I'm having difficulties on how can I possibly join two models in 1 class in views.py.

I have tried django rest framework but that's not the scope of my app.

Here is my code:

```py
    class UserDashboardTemplateView(ListView):
        #I want to insert the ORDER model in this class also
        model = Product
        context_object_name = 'product'
        template_name = 'product/dashboard.html'
```

The data must be displayed in this format:

```
    {% for o in orders %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ o.status }}</td>
          </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you can import Order from models and then use like `Order.objects.all()` or `Order.objects.filter()` according to your case, but I'm not sure about it

Comment: Yes, that's actually the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure – [`ListView`s are just "sugar"](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a44d80f88e22eda24dacef48e368895ebea96635/django/views/generic/list.py#L194) to conveniently get objects from a single place.  You want to drop down to a `TemplateView` instead. (TemplateViews don't do pagination etc. by themselves; if you need that, you'll need to do it yourself or maybe compose two `ListViews` into a single view).

```py
class UserDashboardTemplateView(TemplateView):
    # I want to insert the ORDER model in this class also
    model = Product
    context_object_name = "product"
    template_name = "product/dashboard.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['products'] = Product.objects.all()  # or whatever
        context['orders'] = Order.objects.all()  # or whatever
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks bro! This answer helped me a lot. It's working by the way.